# cant connect to realtime database and it makes entering unity playmode stuck

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

im sure that my unity has no problem and there is no forever loop script in my project, i just watch the part 1 of firebase unity tutorial from firebase youtube channel, there is a problem on my project, because when i do what the video says, and i got infinity loading while trying to enter play mode in unity, im very confuse about it, is there any problem on my dependencies? or ? this is my script trying to write data to my realtime database, is there anything wrong ? please help me fix it, i need realtime database to store some of my app data, already do what that link says, https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*1k5a80u*_ga*MTM3MjQxNjA0My4xNjg1MzcwNDQx*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjcxODA4Ny43LjEuMTY4NjcyMjA4Ni4wLjAuMA..#analytics-enabled

but it still wont connect and please help me

my scripts :

```
`using Firebase;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CheckDepency : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private void Awake()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                // Set up the database reference
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to initialize Firebase: " + task.Result);
            }
        });
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // Example usage: write data to the database
        WriteDataToDatabase("exampleNode", "Hello, Firebase!");
    }

    private void WriteDataToDatabase(string path, string data)
    {
        // Create a new child reference under the root reference
        DatabaseReference childReference = databaseReference.Child(path);

        // Set the value of the child reference asynchronously
        childReference.SetValueAsync(data).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log("Data written to the database successfully!");
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to write data to the database: " + task.Exception);
            }
        });
    }

}`
```

im trying to access analytics and it didnt connect

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your code. To help me better understand, could you please check your log and copy debug logs, warnings and errors that can be found there?

From the looks of your code sample, its likely that the issue is that by the time `DatabaseReference childReference = databaseReference.Child(path);` is called in `WriteDataToDatabase` from `Start()`, `databaseReference` has not been initialized yet.

The `FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith` **must** have been completed prior to using `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance` or `DefaultInstance.RootReference`.

The best way to do this is to call database related setup in the callback from `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith` (as demonstrated in [Firebase for Unity SDK database QuickStart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/blob/bd49417e32303753f0fcc67f1d4cc960f071010e/database/testapp/Assets/Firebase/Sample/Database/UIHandler.cs#L49)) and then note this in a variable or property that subsequent methods that use Firebase can check. An example of this is available in the [Mechahamster](https://github.com/google/mechahamster/blob/9ee186dfe48a35bb4e26369a78e8c350942098c3/Assets/Hamster/Scripts/MainGame.cs#L222) example project.

To demonstrate what might be happening here you can change your `WriteDataToDatabase` method to

```cs
    private void WriteDataToDatabase(string path, string data)
    {

        if(databaseReference == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Do not attempt to use the {nameof(databaseReference)} before it is initialized.");
        }

        // Create a new child reference under the root reference
        DatabaseReference childReference = databaseReference.Child(path);

        // Set the value of the child reference asynchronously
        childReference.SetValueAsync(data).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log("Data written to the database successfully!");
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to write data to the database: " + task.Exception);
            }
        });
    }
```

In your case, you can call `WriteDataToDatabase` in the callback and remove your `Start()` method code.